# Error with markers

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

am trying to put a marker on a map of a location , but it give me error the options , but if i load the map alone it works fine

hier is my code

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     //var map;
>     function initialize() {  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
>             var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("FormView1_LatitudeLabel").textContent);
>             var lng = parseFloat(document.getElementById("FormView1_LongitudeLabel").textContent);
>
>
>             // Creating a map
>
>                     // Creating a LatLng object containing the coordinate for the center of the map  
>                     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
>                     // Creating an object literal containing the properties we want to pass to the map  
>                     var options = {
>                         zoom: 7,
>                         center: latlng,
>                         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
>                     };
>                     // Calling the constructor, thereby initializing the map  
>                     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
>
>                     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
>                         position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
>                         map: map,
>                         title: 'My workplace',
>                         clickable: false,
>                         icon: 'img/factory.png'
>                     });
>                 }
>   }   
>  </script>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

GBrowserIsCompatible() is a V2-method, but the rest of your code is V3, you must decide for a single API-version .

Answer (score 0):

I do not really know what you want, but

```
marker.setMap(map);
```

will show your marker on the map.

With

```
map.panTo(marker.getPosition())
```

you can pan your map to the marker.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The trailing comma on the last item here will cause errors in Internet Explorer:

```
var options = {
                        zoom: 7,
                        center: latlng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    };
```

Should be:

```
var options = {
                        zoom: 7,
                        center: latlng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
```